# Select point with highest value within a buffer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.2, buffer, select

I work with ArcMap 10.2.1 and I created buffers around points. Some buffers contain many points and others just one. I would like to select one point for each buffer, but the points can represent different attributes having different values.

So when I have for example one buffer with two points, one point could be organism one and the second point could be organism two. Organism one has a value 30% and organism two has value 70%. I would like to select organism two and delete organism one from the buffer (file).
Only thing is I have many buffers, with varying amount of points (organisms) and different percentages..So I would like to do it for all the buffers..
I am using modelbuilder as I do not know python.
Does anybody have a suggestion? That would be great!

Comment: This seams to be a work for a spatial database to do with sql.

Comment: I am having trouble picturing what you are trying to describe in words.  Would you be able to edit your Question and include some graphics of your points and buffers, and rows from each to explain the rules you are trying to implement, please?

Comment: Do you have overlapping buffers? Which takes precedence as one buffer could delete valid points for another buffer? Agree with PolyGeo, upload some images of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ah, I have solved the problem. By using identity tool, summary statistics and join.

Answer (score 3):

You can start by assigning the values of the buffers to the points (SPATIAL JOIN, one to many)

Then you use summary statistics to find out the maximum value for each buffer ID

Finally, you concatenate the field values and the buffers ID (field calculator !ID! + '_' + !MAXVALUE! ) and you use this to join your points (keeping only the matching records).

Note that, if your buffer overlap, one point could be the maximum for one buffer area but not for the other buffer area. You'll have to decide what to do with those points.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem by using the identity tool and summary statistics and join..